# Matlab marker inserter roiinput error

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

In matlab I'm trying to draw a marker around an interest area in an image.
The problem is, after I set ROIInput to true I can't use it.

When I use it the following way

```
J = step(markerInserter, I, Pts,[x y height weight]);
```

It gives me the error below:

```
Error using vision.MarkerInserter/step Too many input arguments;
expected 2 (in addition to the object handle), got 3.
```

How can I set the size of the marker as a size of an image I already have?

Comment: How did you create the `MarkerInserter`?  Please show the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

As @rayreng said, please post more of your code.

If you have MATLAB version R2013a or later, you can try the `insertMarker` function, which is easier to use.

Also, from your question it sounds like you are trying to draw a box around a region. You may want to try the `insertShape` function for that, or `vision.ShapeInserter` if you have an older version of MATLAB.